# Selling physical goods in an UWP app

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, payment, uwp

I want to sell physical products in an UWP app - I know that it's not allowed to use the API for IAPs (In-App-Purchases). I found out that there is a [PayPal SDK for .NET](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK) which can be used to handle payments.

Are there any alternatives out there, or do you know best practices to handle the selling of real-world goods inside a mobile app, is there something like an e-commerce system for universal windows apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET SDK is designed for server-side integration, not a distributed binary.

Windows mobile native is not well supported at the moment. I'd recommend opening a web browser to complete the transaction via [Braintree v.zero](https://www.braintreepayments.com/features/paypal).

Comment: Thank you - I am doing it with a redirect to a browser window!